# Converting from Java primitive to wrapper classes

Tags: java, type-conversion, boxing

I am mystified by the behavior of the Java compiler when assigning primitives to wrapper class references. Please see the code below. The lines with comments don't compile.

I don't understand the logic of why:

1. a `byte` can be assigned to a `Byte` or `Short`, but not `Integer` or `Long` reference
2. a `short` can be assigned to a `Byte` or `Short`, but not `Integer` or `Long` reference
3. an `int` can be assigned to a `Byte`, `Short`, or `Integer`, but not `Long` reference
4. a `long` can be assigned to a `Long`, but not `Byte`, `Short` or `Integer` reference

I cannot see the pattern. Any insight into this will be really helpful. 
Thanks.

```
Byte s5 = (byte)7;
Short s6 = (byte)7;
Integer s7 = (byte)7;   // Does not compile
Long s8 = (byte)7;      // Does not compile

Byte s9 = (short)7;
Short s10 = (short)7;
Integer s11 = (short)7; // Does not compile
Long s12 = (short)7;    // Does not compile

Byte s1 = (int)7;
Short s2 = (int)7;
Integer s3 = (int)7;
Long s4 = (int)7;       // Does not compile

Byte s13 = (long)7;     // Does not compile
Short s14 = (long)7;    // Does not compile
Integer s15 = (long)7;  // Does not compile
Long s16 = (long)7;
```

Comment: [JLS-5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I just looked at the link you posted, but it really doesn't deal with the point of my question.

Comment: I thought your question was why are some boxing conversions allowed and some not... Please clarify the *point*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, If you look at my posting, you can see that a primitive short can be narrowed and boxed into Byte without complaint from the compiler, while you cannot box anything other than a long into a Long. The latter makes sense to me, but not the former.

Comment: And what was the point of casting, narrowing and boxing? What *problem* are you trying to solve, and how does this help you solve it?

Comment: It is just a question.. based on something I saw in the Sierra/Bates book. I am trying to understand the logic of this, not trying to solve any particular problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70314/discussion-between-user3516726-and-elliott-frisch).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70355/discussion-between-user3516726-and-elliott-frisch).

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the types of conversions allowed in an [assignment context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Principally:

> Assignment contexts allow the use of **one** of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion
> - a widening primitive conversion
> - a widening reference conversion
> - a boxing conversion optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

(Note my emphasis on *one*.)

Most of your examples that do not compile, for example

```
Integer s11 = (short)7;
```

require *a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion*. This is not a permitted conversion.

But then you might wonder why the following example does compile:

```
Byte s9 = (short)7;
```

This is *a narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion*.

This is a special case:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int` [...] a narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
> - `Byte` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `byte`.
> - `Short` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `short`.
> - `Character` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `char`.

This special case is necessary because there is no way to express an integer literal of a type narrower than `int`.

Comment: I was in a hurry, and thought 'equate' would be understood in the context of what I was saying. I understand that it is an assignment.

Comment: You have pointed out the case of Integer s11 = (short)7, where a widening followed by boxing is required. Yes, I understand that widening followed by boxing is too much for the compiler to handle. However, that doesn't explain why Short s6 = (byte)7;  does compile. Here too, a widening followed by boxing is required, but the compiler seems to be able to handle that fine!

Comment: *"Short s6 = (byte)7"* This is covered by the clause in the 2nd part of my answer: *"Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type short"*.

Comment: I am confused.. that part of your answer talks about a narrowing conversion followed by boxing. What we have in Short s6 = (byte)7; is a widening followed by boxing..  Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Actually I suppose you're right, the JLS doesn't address that case exactly. The possibility I can think of is that a pretty liberal interpretation of the phrase *"In addition..."* could imply that the compiler can also do *widening primitive conversion -> narrowing primitive conversion -> boxing conversion*. In other words the compiler might be allowed to widen `(byte)7` to `int` and then perform *narrowing -> boxing*. It's also perfectly possible javac doesn't adhere completely to the specification or there is some clause somewhere else completely that I don't know about.

Comment: Although if we assume javac adheres to the specification then the liberal interpretation is also probably necessary for, for example, `Character c = (byte)0;` to compile because a conversion from `byte` to `char` is defined as being [a widening followed by a narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be compiler-specific behavior.  When I paste your code into Eclipse, running Java 7, I do not see the compiler errors you report for `short` to `Integer` or `byte` to `Integer`.

Instead, I see `byte`, `short`, and `int` can all be assigned to `Byte`, `Short`, and `Integer`, but not `Long`, and `long` can only be assigned to `Long`.  Interestingly, if you change the variables to primitives instead of wrapper types, the `byte`, `short`, and `int` behavior doesn't change, but now the assignments from the other types to `long` also work.

```
javac 1.7.0_02
           | byte | Byte || short | Short || int | Integer || long | Long |
From byte  | Yes  | Yes  || Yes   | Yes   || Yes | No      || Yes  | No   |
From short | Yes  | Yes  || Yes   | Yes   || Yes | No      || Yes  | No   |
From int   | Yes  | Yes  || Yes   | Yes   || Yes | Yes     || Yes  | No   |
From long  | No   | No   || No    | No    || No  | No      || Yes  | Yes  |

Eclipse Indigo
           | byte | Byte || short | Short || int | Integer || long | Long |
From byte  | Yes  | Yes  || Yes   | Yes   || Yes | Yes     || Yes  | No   |
From short | Yes  | Yes  || Yes   | Yes   || Yes | Yes     || Yes  | No   |
From int   | Yes  | Yes  || Yes   | Yes   || Yes | Yes     || Yes  | No   |
From long  | No   | No   || No    | No    || No  | No      || Yes  | Yes  |
```

Given that different compilers allow different conversions, I suspect the "correct" behavior is not actually spelled out in the JLS.  It seems certain conversions are done under the covers because the compiler writers considered it convenient (e.g. `byte a = (int)1` is allowed but `byte a = (int)1000` is not), not because it's a documented part of the language.

Comment: I get the same as the OP using the Java 7 compiler. Eclipse has its own compiler I believe.

Comment: @dimo414, I am using Java 7.. I rechecked. The behavior is exactly as I wrote above in my question.

Comment: @user3516726 it seems to be compiler-specific behavior, as EJP mentioned.  I've updated my answer after verifying it myself.

Comment: I gave this an upvote because I think the table is useful. I think you should also probably include `char` and `Character` even though the OP didn't ask about them. They have more corner cases that the specification is vague about.

Answer (score 0):

From my research, I found that a byte is an 8-bit signed integer. Shorts are 16-bit signed integers. Therefore I can see why they are compatible, they are both two's complement signed integers, emphasis on **signed**. A long is a 64-bit integer, but it can also be unsigned (considering it has methods for comparing unsigned longs). This would probably explain why your conversions to long are causing errors - you'd be casting a signed byte to a potentially unsigned long. (Source: Reading about primitives at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: There's no issue with unsignedness. Java doesn't have unsigned types, just some utility methods that do arithmetic and comparisons as if unsigned.

Comment: Ah sorry, I came from C++ to Java and I keep forgetting that.