# Widening primitive conversions followed by boxing conversions

Tags: java, type-conversion, jls

This question is related with the post [Converting from Java primitive to wrapper classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335839/converting-from-java-primitive-to-wrapper-classes/48155488#48155488).
If widening primitive conversions followed by boxing conversions are not allowed, the following code
      Short s6 = (byte)7;

Is it a special case or am I wrong?

I've been looking for the entire JLS and I've found nothing about it